# JNIEnv can NOT call method in other c files?

Tags: c, java-native-interface, jnienv

I have two files : MyJni.cpp is the jni file. And MyObject.c is a normal c file.

Here is the MyJni.cpp file's code :

```
 JNIEXPORT  void createMyObject(JNIEnv* env){
     malloc(MyObject)
     MyObject->setEnv(env);

    MyObject->callbackFunc();
}

static Void callback_for_myobject(MyObject * obj){
        JNIEnv* env = obj->m_env;
        Env->NewStringUTF(); //    **OK**
}
```

MyObject.c file is:

```
 void* m_env;
setEnv(void* env){
  m_env = env;

 JNIEnv* pEnv = (JNIEnv*)env;
        pEnv->NewStringUTF();//   **ERROR**
}

Void callbackFunc()
{
    callback_for_myobject(this);
}
```

I saved the JNIEnv to MyObject (maybe should not do this).
And in MyObject , I want to call Jni methods, but it can't .
While I callback to the MyJni file, it works fine.

Why? I can't find out any difference.... 
How can I make it work in MyObject ??

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is your question "I can't call a C++ function from C" ?

Comment: Question is Why JNIEnv can't be used in MyObject Actually. Thanks

Comment: You can't save `JNIEnv*` values. ` malloc(MyObject)` is either senseless or non-compiling, depending on what `MyObject` is, and `Env->NewStringUTF()` and `pEnv->NewStringUTF()` are certainly both senseless. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: I found out why: JNIEnv is a C++ class, can't be used in C file . In C file can use _JNIEnv.
And Yes, should NOT save JniEnv value. 
Thanks for all of you.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why: JNIEnv is a C++ class, can't be used in C file .

In C file can use _JNIEnv.

And Yes, should NOT save JniEnv value. Thanks for all of you.